# Expresión regular que rechace casos específicos

Tags: linux, validación, script, shell, rhel

Mi duda es la siguiente:
Me llega un archivo y quiero validar un campo.

- debe ser alfanumérico
- puede tener ceros en diferentes lugares ejemplo (A1840, 02749, 0AG6384, MVS100)
- **NO DEBE**

  - aceptar puros ceros ejemplo (0,0000,0000000,00000000)
  - pasar de 20 carácteres.

Lo estoy realizando en un Shell en red hat, está separado por *pipes* ejemplo

```
AV193840|01
```

El folio es la primera columna, eso ya lo hago...ya obtengo el dato, solo quiero saber cómo realizar esa validación de que no sea un folio con puros ceros "000000" de 0 a 20 ceros.
Lo guardo en la variable `vfolio`

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A tu pregunta le falta más información, por ejemplo ¿el archivo tiene varias líneas? ¿cada línea tiene varios campos? ¿cómo están separados los campos? ¿qué comando utilizas para _procesar_ el archivo?, ¿qué cosas ya has intentado y no han funcionado?. Lee el artículo y luego edita tu pregunta para mejorar tus probabilidades de obtener buenas respuestas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría una expresión regular de la forma:

```
\((?!00000,\s00000,\s0000000,\s000000)(?!([\d,\s]*[A-Z][\d,\s]*){8,})([A-Z0-9]{5},\s){2}([A-Z0-9]{7},\s)[A-Z0-9]{6}\)
```

Como verás tiene algunos grupos con los símbolos `(?!)` a eso se le conoce como *negative lookahead*, es decir, nos asegura que nuestro resultado no contiene eso o la expresión regular no se cumple, por ello pongo primero tus dos casos frontera:

- Qué no tenga puros ceros

  ```
  (?!00000,\s00000,\s0000000,\s000000)
  ```
- Qué no tenga más de 7 carcateres alfabéticos

  ```
  (?!([\d,\s]*[A-Z][\d,\s]*){8,})
  ```

Después de ello cualquier expresión que quieras usar para validar tu formato.

Quiero hacerte notar que este tipo de pensamiento te orienta a una solución recursiva, y que idealmente debes usar una heurística de tipo estadística para maximizar la velocidad a que encuentra las coincidencias.

De igual manera te conmino a visitar nuestro [wiki de expresiones regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223553/qu%C3%A9-significa-esta-expresi%C3%B3n-regular-referencia-de-expresiones-regulares) por si alguna de las funcionalidades allí citadas te sirviera.