# Como hacer un Regex para mas de una repeticiones

Tags: java, regex

tengo este codigo que reemplaza  dos guiones por uno, pero si aparecen mas guiones ya no funciona, como lo puedo solucionar utilizando regex?

```
cadActual = nuevaCad.replaceAll("--", "-");
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa esta expresión regular? (Referencia de expresiones regulares)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223553/qu%c3%a9-significa-esta-expresi%c3%b3n-regular-referencia-de-expresiones-regulares)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cadActual = nuevaCad.replaceAll("-{2,}", "-");
```

Básicamente dice que si encuentra 2 o mas ocurrencias de guión juntas, las reemplaza por uno solo.

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda argumentar tu respuesta pues solo poner código sin contexto y explicación se considera de baja calidad