# Expresiones regulares. De una palabra seleccionar del tercer caracter en adelante

Tags: regex

¿Cómo puedo con una expresión regular seleccionar desde desde el tercer caracter en adelante de cada palabra?

Por ejemplo, dada la siguiente entrada con las palabras:

```
manzana limon uva el la naranja tomate cereza coco
```

La expresión regular iría seleccionando:

```
nzana, mon, a, ranja, mate, reza, co
```

(separo por comas cada ocurrencia de la búsqueda mediante expresión regular)

La herramienta a utilizar sería regex101.com (PCRE)

Tengo dudas para lograrlo: No sé si tengo que utilizar `\b`, o quizas un grupo de captura o grupo condicional.

Gracias.

Comment: Esto es en algun lenguaje en particular? DE paso, intentaste algo?

Comment: intento fallido /.{2}(.+)$/gm. Otro (?=[\b[a-z]{2}])\w+

Comment: El código que usas y los errores que genera / el resultado inesperado se ponen en la pregunta, editándola.

Comment: Pero cual es la pregunta, presenta tu solucion y en donde tienes problemas.

Comment: Te recomiendo primero revisar una referencia de expresiones regulares https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223553/qu%C3%A9-significa-esta-expresi%C3%B3n-regular-referencia-de-expresiones-regulares/223555#223555

Comment: Creo que la pregunta está ahora clara y quizás se podría reabrir... CC: @gbianchi

Comment: AP abandono la pregunta hace tiempo. Abrirla no tiene ningun sentido porque no va a tener una respuesta correcta. Y como si fuera poco, la edicion deberia ser rechazada porque cambio todo el sentido original de la pregunta. En estos casos, se recomienda que hagas una nueva pregunta y agregues la respuesta si asi se puede discutir y aceptar.

Answer (score 4):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
\w\w\K\w+
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/BfbeF6/2/).

**Explicado:**

```
\w\w   # Dos caracteres
\K     # Ignoramos lo encontrado anteriormente
\w+    # De uno a más caracteres
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta te funciona:

```
\b *..(.*?)\b
```

- `\b` representa un *word boundary*, o sea un inicio o final de palabra. Encajaría con el inicio de la primera palabra, o con el final de la palabra anterior para cada una de las siguientes.
- `*` es para "comerse los espacios" por si el `\b` había encajado con el final de palabra de la anterior.
- `..` son las dos primeras letras de la palabra que en que estamos
- `(.*?)` es un grupo de captura *non-greedy* que capturará todo lo que pueda hasta llegar al siguiente:
- `\b`, que es otro *word boundary*, o sea, el final de la palabra.

Demo [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/1V9Cgf/1)

Comment: o quizas \b *\w{2}(\w*?)\b

Comment: @ViciniEdgar Es un poco redundante usar `\w` ya que eso significa "word-character", lo cual por definición es cualquier cosa que esté entre dos "word-boundaries". Por tanto todo lo que mi expresión capturaría con el `.*` serían también "word-characters". ¿O estás pensando en algún caso que se me escapa?

Comment: como sustituimos lo seleccionado en verde con la nada, eliminar?

Comment: Depende del lenguaje de programación. Muchos lenguajes tienen una función de substitución que reemplaza lo que encaje con cada grupo de captura por otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/7dZxvU/2

expresion regular: `(?<=ma)nzana`

Utiliza una declaración positiva de búsqueda hacia atrás (positive lookbehind assertion)