# ¿Cómo evito que una expresión regular sea greedy (avariciosa) y coja tanto como pueda?

Tags: regex

Supongamos que tengo la cadena siguiente:

```
hola23adios23bla
```

Y quiero extraer el texto que aparece antes del `23` utilizando expresiones regulares, para tener de resultado:

```
hola23
adios23
```

Si utilizo la expresión siguiente me coge todo, pues el [metacarácter `*`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/223582/83) es avaricioso, voraz o, en inglés, *greedy*:

```
.*23
```

Es decir, me extrae un único resultado: `hola23adios23`, como se ve [en la demo](https://regex101.com/r/NW98tx/3).

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la expresión regular no sea avariciosa y me devuelve `hola23` y `adios23`? Intenté con `.+23` pero devuelve lo mismo, `hola23adios23`.

Comment: He visto que este tema no está recogido en ninguna pregunta específica de forma curada, así que me tomo la libertad de añadir esta pregunta preparada de antemano para que sirva de explicación canónica. Toda sugerencia o comentario será bienvenido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes utilizar un cuantificador *non-greedy*, es decir, no avaricioso ni voraz:

```
.*?23
  ^
```

Puedes [probarlo en una Demo online](https://regex101.com/r/NW98tx/2).

Al añadir el metacarácter `?` conseguimos que la expresión haga coincidir con la menor cantidad posible de caracteres.

En este caso particular, si encuentra "hola23" que coincide, ya se para. De lo contrario, seguiría buscando hasta encontrar el último 23 y devolvería "hola23adios23".