# En expresiones regulares que es lo que hace : o para que se utiliza

Tags: python, regex

Ya busque en la documentación de Python pero no logro encontrar que es lo que hace, pongo un ejemplo

```
re.findall("([A-Z a-z]*): B", grades)
```

Entiendo que se esta buscando el patrón que inicie con mayúsculas y seguido tenga carácter  en minúsculas. Lo que no comprendo es que hace después de ":" o para que lo usan.

Comment: **No** estas buscando un patrón que inicie con mayúsculas, el patrón inicia con una letra de la **A** a la **z** que puede ser tanto mayúsculas como minúsculas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa esta expresión regular? (Referencia de expresiones regulares)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223553/qu%c3%a9-significa-esta-expresi%c3%b3n-regular-referencia-de-expresiones-regulares)

Answer (score 1):

El caracter ":" no tiene significado especial dentro de una expresión regular; es simplemente otro caracter más. Al usarlo estás diciendo que en esa posición, la cadena examinada debe contener un ":".

**Ejemplos**

```
re.findall(r"(\w+):", "Raúl Gomez: 10 Aprobado") => ['Gomez']
```

porque "Gomez" es la ocurrencia de múltiples '\w` seguida de un ":".

Otro:

```
re.findall(r"(\d+),\d+", "10,4 11,5 12 ,6") => ['10', '11']
```

Esta expresión busca y captura uno o más dígitos `(\d+)` seguidos de una coma "," y luego más digitos. Sólo nos interesa capturar la parte entera.

De los cuatro valores en el ejemplo, `12` no tiene parte decimal y `,6` no tiene parte entera, por lo que no calzan con la expresión.