# Captura de grupos. Referencia anterior o inversa

Tags: java, regex

¿Qué significado tiene el capturar en un grupo una referencia anterior?

Por ejemplo en la expresión:

```
"(\w+)\s( \1)"
```

¿Qué función tiene `"( \1)"`?

Comment: \1 encontrar digitos repetidos

Comment: se puede hacer sin agruparlo, lo que no se es, que cambia si agrupas una referencia; para que agruparla, me refiero a " ( ) " los parenteis con una referencia dentro

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa esta expresión regular? (Referencia de expresiones regulares)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223553/qu%c3%a9-significa-esta-expresi%c3%b3n-regular-referencia-de-expresiones-regulares)

Answer (score 0):

No tiene ninguna utilidad generar un grupo para capturar un texto que ya se capturó. Es totalmente redundante.

---

**Explicado de cero**

`(\w+)` es el primer grupo, porque es el primer grupo de paréntesis.

El hecho de que sea un grupo genera una *captura*. Eso te permite obtener el texto que coincidió por separado, o incluso usarlo dentro de la misma expresión regular.

`\1` es una referencia hacia atrás. Hace referencia al texto capturado por el grupo 1 (`\2` hace referencia al grupo 2, y así sucesivamente).

Por ejemplo, `(\w+)\s+\1` puede coincidir con 1 o más caracteres de palabra (A-Za-z_0-9), seguido de 1 o más espacios, seguidos por *exactamente* el mismo texto que coincidió al principio.

Es decir, va a coincidir con cualquiera de estos textos

```
a        a
bla bla
@@@texto        texto!!!!!!
```

Pero no va a coincidir con

```
a   x    a
bla blX
texto!!! texto!!!
```

---

**En resumen**

Como el regex `(\w+)\s+( \1)` puede coincidir si y sólo si coincide con un texto duplicado, sería tan redundante como asignar 2 variables, una con un espacio + el texto de la otra.

Tampoco me imagino un caso práctico para exigir un espacio luego de `\s+`.

---

**Caso en que sí podría servir**

*Podría* llegar a usarse en una expresión donde `(\1)` sea opcional, para verificar si esa parte del patrón coincidió o no. Ejemplo:

```
(\w+)\s+(?:(\1)|otro texto)
```

Y luego en el código verificamos si existe el grupo 2.