# Validar constraseña con JS

Tags: javascript, regex, validación

Necesito comprobar que un valor(clave) tiene:

- Mínimo 8 caracteres.
- Mayúsculas y minúsculas.
- Números.
- Puede contener `!` o `?`, pero ningún otro carácter especial.

Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```js
function enRango(x, min, max) {
    return ((x - min) * (x - max) <= 0);
}

const clave = document.getElementById('clave');

function comprobarContraseña(clave) {
  let resul = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < clave.length; i++) {
    if (!enRango(clave.charCodeAt(i), 34, 47) || !enRango(clave.charCodeAt(i), 58, 62)) {
      if (minusculas.test(clave)) {
        if (numeros.test(clave)) {
          resul = 1;
          console.log('has entrado hasta el final');
          return resul;
        }
      }
    } else {
      resul = 1;
      return resul;
    }
    if (minusculas.test(clave) && numeros.test(clave)) {
      console.log('estas en el minusculas y numeros');
      return resul;
    }
  }
}
```

`minusculas` y `numeros` son dos expresiones regulares que he creado, pero al no tener mucho conocimiento en la materia creo que tengo algún fallo a la hora de comprobar.

```js
const minusculas = new RegExp('^[a-z]+$');
const numeros = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
```

Creo que puede comprobarse todo directamente con una Expresión Regular pero no sé exactamente como hacerlo.

Comment: Por qué crees que tienes un fallo? Falla? Probaste el código? qué error encuentas?

Comment: Si le paso un texto que tenga mas de 8 en longitud me lo da correcto.
Si meto cualquier carácter especial me lo reconoce bien igual.
Basicamente no compruba bien por la funcion comprobarContraseña, en ésta habrá algun error.

Comment: Ninguna de las expresiones o validaciones que tiene ese método comprueba la longitud de la contraseña y eso no necesita una expresión regular. Eso _falta_. Lo otro es que valides POR SEPARADO cada atributo de la contraseña para no complicar lo que puede ser simple. Valida que tenga minúsculas y retorna algo cuando no se cumpla, luego mayúsculas y lo mismo, luego números...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

las validaciones las debes hacer una por una, para ello te recomiendo guiarte de la [referencia de expresiones regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223553/qu%c3%a9-significa-esta-expresi%c3%b3n-regular-referencia-de-expresiones-regulares).

No es que en teoría no puedas lograrlo en una sola expresión regular, pero será mucho más complejo.

Para unir todas las validaciones usa el operador lógico `&&`.

Hay dos formas de definir una expresión regular en javascript, la que pusiste en la que debes de escapar los caracteres y la forma ya escapada, donde pones tu expresión regular entre slashes (`/`)

Para verificar si una validación se cumple con algún texto a tu expresión regular le llamas su método `test` y su parámetro debe ser una cadena.

Al final te quedará algo así:

```js
function comprobarContraseña(el) {
  const clave = el.value;
  const ochocaracteres = /.{8,}/.test(clave)
  console.log("contiene al menos 8 caracteres:", ochocaracteres)
  const mayymin = /(?:[A-Z])/.test(clave) && /(?:[a-z])/.test(clave)
  console.log("Mayusculas y minusculas:", mayymin)
  const numeros = /(?:\d)/.test(clave)
  console.log("números:", numeros)
  const noespecial = !/[^!?A-Za-z\d]/.test(clave)
  console.log("contiene ! o ?, pero no otro caracter especial:", noespecial)
  const valida=ochocaracteres && mayymin && numeros && noespecial
  console.log("contraseña válida:", valida, "\n\n");
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="comprobarContraseña(this)" />
```